# xplane11 control pilot aircraft freeze loose settings

Tags: xplane

I use for professional piloting over airport Xplane 11 on windows 10 home, and sometimes by hour this software freeze stop running while I piloting real a airfreighter in sky, and to doing revoring is slow as 5 minutes minimum, also to start 3D world for improve view, and hd camera in board pilot cabin. Also to retake recovery the control piloting on ground the aircraft and the remote view is wrong of parameters angles. What about the last update in version older to quick restart, avoid freeze and recover more high keep the cockpit equipment settings whithout reload the saved file before a new time to be secure a new bug crach this software, what I use daily and know it since last years.

Comment: Hello, what about boat objects loading in same time new air flight in this software, real is not it for what in airport these ships even true docked can not going sailor without leaving on, even in real metal gray fears close by internation airport with a llot of passengers, workers.

Comment: Invalid move object as boat carrier or frigate not real as same postion does a crash software very fast and dangerous for air line piloting, do you have a solution to avoid a program exit without losing control an aircraft ?

Answer (score 0):

there a solution, increasing virtual memory and file preference screen video : https://www.x-plane.com/kb/configuring-x-plane-to-use-less-virtual-memory/

Answer (score 0):

Reducing X-Plane’s Virtual Memory Use :

There are a few ways you can reduce the amount of virtual memory that X-Plane needs to operate.

The first thing you can do is remove add-ons.  Plugins, custom airplanes, and custom scenery can all increase the amount of virtual memory that X-Plane uses.  Try removing add-ons and see if the problem goes away.  Add-ons can also increase the amount of memory that X-Plane itself uses. You may have to mix and match add-ons depending on your activities.

The second thing you can do is turn down X-Plane’s settings.  Here are some settings that make a difference in virtual memory usage.

```
AI traffic.  More planes uses more memory, and more complex and higher detail planes use more memory.
Texture resolution: turn texture compression on – it saves a lot of memory.  Turn down texture res as needed.  In particular, do not run with extreme res and uncompressed textures.
Trees – turn down the forest density to save memory.
4x SSAA – when in HDR mode, turn off 4x SSAA if you use a large monitor or a large window size.
If needed, turn down object density.
```

Comment: Also can keeping real hour for visual light have tick date hour real on preparing the air flight and aircraft.